# Callback jq-метода .animate()

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять логику происходящего

```js
var running = false;

console.log(running + '1');

if(!running){
  running = true;

  console.log(running + '2'); 

  $('#carousel_wrap').animate({
    'margin-left': '-70px'     
  }, 1000,  function(){
    console.log(running + '3');

    running = false;
  }); 

  console.log(running + '4');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="carousel_wrap" class="carousel_wrap">
  ccccc
</div>
```

На страничке http://jsfiddle.net/RWC4Y/ происходит анимация, переменную running я вывел в консоль 4 раза и в результате получил такой вывод:

```
false1
true2
true4
true3
```

Я не понимаю почему по завершению анимации `running = false`, ведь в коллбеке функции .animate() я поставил инструкцию `running = false`. Как я понимаю, коллбэк выполняется после того как анимация завершила свою работу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Язык `JavaScript` - это асинхронный язык. Если разобрать по этапам ваш скрипт, то получается:

1. `running = false;` в консоль выводится `false1`
2. `running = true;` в консоль выводится `true2`
3. Анимируем изменение отступа у элемента, после сразу выводим в консоль `console.log(running + '4')`
4. По завершению анимации срабатывает `callback`, выводится сообщение в консоль: `true3`, переменная `running` изменяется на значение `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Да, callback выполниться только после завершения анимации. Т.е. ваш вывод в консоль **console.log(running + '4');** всегда будет срабатываться раньше, чем **console.log(running + '3');**, за исключением случая, когда продолжительность выполнения анимации (*duration*), будет равна "нулю".